# I need assistance with a program that would find words starting with a letter i type in

Tags: python-3.x

Right now all my code does is find all the `a`'s in all my words. All I want it to do is find words that start with the letter I type using that letter to find the words. E.g. `A` would find the words `activity`, `again` and `ago`. I have tried looking every where and can't find the answer I need.

```
dictionary=["activity","again","ago","begin","behaviour","beyond","camp","cannon","cell","discussion","doctor","display","else","estimate","establish","fudge","flight","fight","gear","great","grunt","how","hoe","house","impact","image","implication","just","job","judge","keep","key","kai"]
newlist=[]
choice = ''
while choice != 'q':

    choice = input("?")
    if choice == 'a':
    for a in dictionary:
        newlist.append(choice.lower())
        print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dictionary=["activity","again","ago","begin","behaviour","beyond","camp","cannon","cell","discussion","doctor","display","else","estimate","establish","fudge","flight","fight","gear","great","grunt","how","hoe","house","impact","image","implication","just","job","judge","keep","key","kai"]
newlist=[]
choice = ''
while choice != 'q':

choice = input("?")
if choice == 'a':
    for item in dictionary:
        if(item[0] == choice):
            newlist.append(item)
    print(newlist)
```

Your above code isn't checking against the first character of each item in the dictionary. It is simply running through every item in the dictionary and appending your "choice" (in this case 'a') to the "newList" and then printing the current items in "newList"

To fix that you need to check the first letter of each item in your dictionary against your choice and then only append those particular items to your "newList"

Comment: Thanks for the help! I now am trying to solve the looping problem after I print the array but I'll be able to sort that out.

Comment: let me know if you run into any more trouble :)

Answer (score 1):

Python strings actually have a `startswith` method :) It's equivalent to `string[0]` in your case.

```
dictionary=["activity","again","ago","begin","behaviour","beyond","camp","cannon","cell","discussion","doctor","display","else","estimate","establish","fudge","flight","fight","gear","great","grunt","how","hoe","house","impact","image","implication","just","job","judge","keep","key","kai"]
newlist=[]
choice = ''
while choice != 'q':
    choice = input("?")
    for a in dictionary:
        if a.startswith(choice.lower()):
            newlist.append(a)
    print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase any one needs the code and runs into the code printing for awhile. This should help with that:

```
count = 0
while count < len(newlist):
    count = count + 1
    print(newlist)
    length = len(newlist)
```